# Сланцы - откуда название?

Tags: этимология

Насколько я знаю, сланцами называют в народе род обуви без задников. Точнее не скажу: то ли вид комнатных тапочек, то ли резиновые пляжные шлепанцы, вроде вьетнамок.
А почему их так называют? По-моему, сланец - это вид минерала и к обуви он точно не имеет никакого отношения.
Я смутно помню, что у этого названия какая-то интересная история, но какая именно?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В Советском Союзе известным изготовителем резиновых шлёпанцев был завод «Полимер» в городе Сланцы Ленинградской области. Многие покупатели полагали, что выдавленное на подошвах слово «Сланцы» это название обуви. Далее слово вошло в активный словарный запас и превратилось в синоним слова «шлёпанцы». Вот так, оказывается, все просто. Поэтому если вы хотите купить подобную обувь в зарубежных интернет-магазинах, то поиск по слову "сланцы" не принесет вам никаких результатов. У иностранцев то не было такого города.

Источник: http://xn----7sbfc3aaqnhaffdukg9p.xn--p1ai/blog/istoriya-poyavleniya-slovaslantsy-

Answer (score 0):

Ши́фер (нем. Schiefer — сланец) — строительный материал. Природный шифер — это плитки, получаемые раскалыванием слоистых горных пород сланцев. Обработанные таким образом сланцы служат кровельным материалом для крыш.

Сланец  из группы слов стлать, стелить,  стланец.